# What does the word "Comprehension" mean in the Axiom of Comprehension?

Tags: terminology, math-history, axioms

I understand roughly what the Axiom of Comprehension means, that any predicate can be used to construct a set of the elements that satisfy the predicate.  But in English terms, where does the word "Comprehension" come from?  I assume it is from "comprehensive", as in "covering everything," or something of that ilk, and not "comprehension" as in "understanding."

Can anyone explain the connection to the usual English meanings of the word?

Comment: Comprehend: include, comprise, or encompass.
"a divine order comprehending all men" -Google search for "comprehend definition"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant sense of *comprehend* is ‘to include, comprise, or encompass’, which is indeed the sense reflected in the adjective *comprehensive*. The axiom schema of comprehension allows us to form sets that *comprise* or *include* all elements of a given set that have some particular property. (It’s also called the axiom schema of specification: we form sets by *specifying* a property that their members must satisfy.)